# Calling JSOM inside and Outlook Add In

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I want to use JSOM inside an Outlook Add In (not a VSTO but a javascript Add In)

So I well create my add in and at this point I did not publish it (maybe it's important since the addin is hosted in localhost)

When the add in is called (it's a panel that has a button and when clicked it calls a function), the .html basically contains:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"
        type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://MYTENANT-my.sharepoint.com/personal/pablo_MYTENANT_com/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://MYTENANT-my.sharepoint.com/personal/pablo_MYTENANT_com/_layouts/15/sp.js">
</script>
                var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

                var website = context.get_web();

                context.load(website);
                context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                    console.log("JSOM: Success");
                }, function (sender, args) {
                    console.log("JSOM: Error: "+args.get_message());
                });
```

The problem is that I get JSOM: error: Unexpected response data from server.

Is there any obvious problem here? I guess that it's related to the fact it is "authenticated" to Sharepoint... it's like if I assume that it must self-authenticate while it may not... or maybe the problem is that it is hosted locally and the javascript runs locally creating security problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Your add-in must authenticate to Sharepoint.

Consider enabling Single Sign-On for your add-ins. Check out [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins) on this matter.

Also, I recommend using graph API with office add-ins. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0)